# Consultar dos tablas y uso de min()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Partimos de dos tablas:

```
Aminales: ID_animal, nombre, especie, incenter  
          1          Toby    2         1  
          2          Micke   2         1  
          3          Jake    2         1  
          4          Tom     2         1  

Entradas: ID_entrada, ID_animal, municipio  
          1           1          Las Rosas  
          2           2          Coslada  
          3           3          Las Rosas  
          4           4          Madrid  
          5           3          Coslada  
          6           2          Coslada
```

Lo que necesito es sacar la cantidad de animales que están dentro del centro en la actualidad (`incenter=1`) y son perros(2) por cada municipio. Como se ve en las tablas, el animal 3 Jake ha sido entregado al centro de animales en dos ocasiones, `ID_entrada` 3 y 5. Pero solo necesitamos la `ID_entrada` mas baja para que este solo aparezca como entregado desde su municipio original, en este caso `Las Rosas`. Da igual la cantidad de veces que haya entrado desde otros municipios tras ser adoptado y devuelto al centro.

El resultado de la consulta debería ser:

```
Madrid: Tom (total 1)  
Las Rosas: Toby, Jake (total 2)  
Coalada: Micke (total 1)
```

Lo he intentando con esta consulta:

```
SELECT animales.nombre, animales.ID_animal, entradas.ID_entrada 
FROM animales 
left JOIN entradas ON (animales.ID_animal = entradas.ID_animal AND incenter=1 AND especie=2 AND entradas.ID_entrada=(select min(ID_entrada) from entradas where municipio=$ID_municipio)
```

No consigo hacer que funcione. ¿Se les ocurre algo?

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas usar el `min`?

Comment: Disculpad mi torpeza, es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow, la respuesta a tu pregunta esta bajo la respuesta de Santi92

Comment: Por favor, puedes [edit] tu pregunta para incluir una muestra de tus datos en las tablas envueltas. Luego preséntanos el resultado deseado basado en esa muestra. Sin tener una vista de los datos, aunque sea solo una muestra, es muy dificil de realmente entender tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas , podes intentar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM animales a INNER JOIN entradas e 
ON a.id_animal=e.id_animal WHERE a.especie=2 AND a.incenter=1 GROUP BY e.municipio
```

Comment: Upss se me olvido lo mas importante.
 Cada animal puede tener varias entradas ya que este puede haber sido adoptado a otro mucipio y haber vuelto desde ese otro municipio. por lo que necesito el que solo coja el valor municipio del ID_entrada mas bajo, si no es este debe obiarlo o me aparecera en el total de cada uno de lo municipios donde haya podido ser adoptado.

COUNT(*) adminte mas opciones? como poder sacar el nombre para poder verificar si esta cogiendo los animales correctos?

Answer (score 0):

No sé muy bien como has definido la base de datos, pero con el siguiente código, funciona lo que quieres:

```
CREATE TABLE animales(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    nombre VARCHAR(35), 
    especie INT, 
    incenter INT
);

CREATE TABLE entradas(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    id_animal INT, 
    municipio INT
);


SELECT COUNT(*), municipio 
FROM animales a JOIN entradas e ON a.id=e.id_animal 
WHERE incenter=1 AND especie=2 GROUP BY municipio;
```

El min() no te debería hacer falta. Si haces todo bien, no va a estar en dos municipios al mismo tiempo por tanto el incenter=1 ya te filtra por el que está actualmente. De hecho, si coges el mínimo de id_entrada y el animal ha cambiado varias veces de municipio, no contará ninguna tupla puesto que el incenter en el mínimo sería 0.

Comment: Hola Pablo, el incenter es para saber si el animal esta en el centro por lo que vale 0 o 1. Lo que necesita el cliente es saber de los animales que estan en el centro cuantos de ellos vienen de que municipios. Registros de ENTRADA el animal puede tener varios; puede haber sido recogido originalmente en coslada, llevado al centro (generado entrada municipio Coslada) ser adoptado por alguien de LasRosas y dias despues ser devuelto. Con lo que se genera otro registro en ENTRADAS que no contiene el origen Coslada. Tengo que listar ese animal como dentro del centro proviniente de Coslada.

Comment: SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entradas e1 WHERE e1.municipio=e.municipio), municipio, nombre
FROM animales a JOIN entradas e ON a.id=e.id_animal 
WHERE incenter=1 AND especie=2 ;

Comment: Eso es lo que podrías hacer para sacar la información que quieres, pero no podrías sacar todos los nombres en una única tupla. Ahora tienes que ver como visualizarlo en el lenguaje que uses,

Answer (score 0):

Segun ejecuto esta consulta en el PHPMyAdmin los resultados son los deseados.
Despues solo faltaria ir revisando desde php si el municipio pertenece a la columna actual para sumar uno al total.

```
SELECT min(entradas.ID_entrada) as minimo, entradas.ID_entrada, animales.ID_animal, animales.nombre, entradas.municipio 
FROM entradas, animales 
WHERE animales.ID_animal = entradas.ID_animal AND animales.incenter =1 AND animales.especie =2
GROUP BY ID_animal
ORDER BY `animales`.`ID_animal` ASC
```